# Superscript/Subscript Shortcut

Tags: feature-request

The superscript (`<sup>`) and subscript (`<sub>`) HTML tags can be quite useful when answering (or asking) questions, and it eludes me as to why there isn't a button for it in the question/answer editor.

Is there a reason for this, or has it just been overlooked or deemed unnecessary?

Comment: This should be asked at [meta.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii I considered that, but I thought it would be more relevant here. (Given that it is more language based.)

Comment: I'm sure it would be useful in Chemistry and plenty of other sites too. Because the formatting is shared by all sites they won't implement anything just for English.se.

Comment: @curiousdannii Of course. I just love this community :) If it gets enough reception here I will take it over to the main site.

Comment: I recently needed to add a superscript-width letter space to an answer, and tried two unsuccessful coding possibilities (_superscript_ and _super_) before giving up and simply hunting through answers until I found one that included the proper code for superscript. A superscript button would have been much more convenient.

Comment: @SvenYargs Being a programmer myself, the code doesn't bother me (I love code!); it's more the fact that it's a bit of a pain to type out!

Comment: I'm sure I've learned and forgotten that particular code a half-dozen times in the past ten years. I don't spend much time adding HTML tags these days, and I use _sup_ just rarely enough not to remember it when I need it.